# Xcode Cocoa App. Big image resizing window

Tags: xcode, image, cocoa, window

Good afternoon.
I set pins (alignment constrains) are 0 from all sides to Image View and when app is loaded, window becomes larger. Window's size is equal image's size. But i want image's size decreases to window's size.
How can i do it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image view's Compression Resistance priority is higher than `NSLayoutPriorityWindowSizeStayPut` (500). So, the image view resists compressing its content more strongly than the window resists changes to its size.

Decrease the Compression Resistance priority of the image view to be lower than 500.